# How to launch .exe from vbscript on windows server 2003

Tags: vbscript, windows-server-2003

I've got a script which needs to run on various different versions of windows server, including 2003. Yeah, I already KNOW it's "unsupported".

My script has to launch an executable, in a hidden window (though the code to do this is not shown below, because I was asked to cut it down to the bare minimum). I'm currently using win32_Process.Create as follows:

```
Set objProcess = GetObject("winmgmts:root\cimv2:Win32_Process")
errReturn = objProcess.Create("C:\myprog.exe", null, null, intProcessID)
```

This works ok on 2008 and 2012, but it is to be failing on 2003 with error code 3 "Insufficient privilege" returned in `errReturn`. It also works when run through cmd.exe, as an ordinary user, but the parent program is a service, check_mk_agent.exe, and so is not an "ordinary user". This script is run as one of check_mk_agent.exe's plugins.

I'm now going to work out how to use `runas` to try to simulate running it as the same user as the service runs as.

Comment: *"but seems to be failing on 2003"* - Please [edit] the question and elaborate some more, what happens or doesn't happen, what errors you receive etc.

Comment: Is this the _absolute minimum_ (readable) code you can write to do this on 2008/2012? If not, please write a [mcve] to illustrate the exact issue, and make sure that there are no hidden issues.

Answer (score 0):

The two most common ways to launch a .exe from vbscript is WScript.Shell **Run** and **Exec** method. The main difference between the two is that you can capture the StdIn/StdOut/StdErr with the Exec method because applications are run in a child command shell.

Exec example:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("calc")
```

Run example:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "%windir%\notepad " & WScript.ScriptFullName
```

Comment: This indeed will work, but the OP is asking about using WMI. There could be a good reason they are using WMI to create the process instead of `WScript.Shell`. In which case this has been answered before multiple times. If you are new to [so] would recommend reading through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if you haven't already.

Comment: Unfortunately, I ended up using WMI because I need a hidden window, and don't want to redirect stdout. I also want the child process to carry on running when the launching script terminates (though I'm not sure that is a problem with Run or Exec), but don't they also wrap the process in a cmd shell?